# How to keep Background while using Shadow Catcher?

Tags: transparency, lighting, shadows, hdri, shadowcatcher

I am trying to Create a Chocolate-Bar like something on a Marble Background (Plane with Material Applied)

I have **added One of Blender's Default HDRI** as Lighting & **No Other lighting in the Scene.**. As HDRI's light is creating the look i wanted.

I have checked **Shadow Catcher** . Everything is working fine , But the Shadow Catcher is making the Background Transparent.

**I am trying to get Shadows but also want to Keep the Marble Plane Background .**

I am very new to Blender. Please Guide Me.

[image: Simple Scene with no other light than HDRI]

[image]